# How to make GTK application use the theme options configured in the GNOME Tweak Tool (and not the KDE's GTK configuration) when I'm under GNOME?

Tags: opensuse, gnome3, theme, kde4

I'm using **openSUSE 13.1** initially installed as a **KDE4** Desktop environment (it's the default corporate install at my work).
Now I would like to use the GNOME desktop. So, I installed **GNOME 3.10** with the standard openSUSE gnome desktop pattern through zypper (`patterns-openSUSE-gnome`).

Now, my problem is that under the GNOME desktop, the GNOME Tweak Tool configuration is completely ignored for pure GTK apps (it is ok for full GNOME apps like `gedit` or `yast-gnome`).
GTK applications actually use the settings found under `KDE System Settings` > `Application` > `GTK`.

I have an older openSUSE desktop (12.3 / KDE4 / Gnome 3.6.2) that works correctly :

- Under KDE : GTK apps are themed using `KDE System Settings` > `Application` > `GTK` settings.
- Under GNOME : GTK apps are themed using `GNOME Tweak Tool`.

It seems that under GNOME, KDE-GTK configuration is being used in favor of GNOME Tweak Tool configuration.

**How to make GTK application use the theme options configured in the GNOME Tweak Tool (and not the KDE's GTK configuration) when I'm under GNOME ?**

**EDIT:** To make sure the problem didn't came from the corporate pre-install I did the following test in a VM :

1. Install a fresh openSUSE 13.1 with GNOME Desktop only (choose GNOME in the install dialog) and log in using GNOME :

   - All apps display well (yast, gedit, firefox)
2. Install the KDE4 openSUSE pattern, then log in using KDE4, then logout and log back using GNOME :

   - **Icons in yast (gnome yast) get changed by KDE4 icons**, besides that, it has the GNOME/GTK look
   - Gedit still display well (default GNOME/GTK look)
   - **Firefox and Meld have the KDE4 oxygen look**

So it seems that the problem comes from this version of KDE4 (the one that comes with openSUSE 13.1) that takes over GTK whether or not the desktop is KDE4...
In the past, KDE4 was more gentle ...

Comment: You could install the `gtk-chtheme` app and use that.  It should work regardless of DE, window manager, etc.

Comment: Thanks - same prooblem and `gtk-chtheme` works perfectly :)

Comment: i got mine from [here](http://packman.inode.at/suse/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/Extra/x86_64/) and installed with `rpm -i`. the link in [pkgs.org](https://opensuse.pkgs.org/tumbleweed/packman/gtk-chtheme-0.3.1-1.87.x86_64.rpm.html) appears to be broken.